# UITableView click drag performance problems

Tags: uitableview

I've trying to manually implement a click and drag behavior on UITableView cells (that is, without going into edit mode).

To do this the cells are slid out of the way of the moving cell by deleting and inserting rows as appropriate, and moving the cell to the new location.

However, it turns out that when the data is backed up by an NSFetchedResultsController the cell movement becomes jerky since each row deletion/insertion causes the NSFetchedResultsController to do a lot of work.

I compared this to the standard UITableView cell movement and of course my delegate is only called back once at the end of the drag. As a result it's nice and smooth.

Does anyone have a suggestion that could help solve this issue? Is there a complete reimplementation of UIViewController out there that allows for drag and drop?

Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this issue. Before the drag starts a take a copy of the current state of the data model. This is the model that I manipulate during the drag, so there are no modifications to the managed context. Once the drag is finished I update the data mode just once.